# Is there a way to define more than one itemtemplate in the default treeview?

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

Or is my only option to extend the original treeview if I want that capability?

I want something like this, but with the two itemspresenters having two different templates defined so that they both use the same items, but apply a different template to create controls in those two spots.

```
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <wpfExp:SignalNameBox x:Name="TreeViewTimeTextBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
                  Height="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfExp:GraphViewer}}, Path=GraphHeight}"
                  Width="200"
                  Margin="19,0,0,0"
                  MainText="Time" 
                />
            <wpfExp:SignalGraphAxis 
                x:Name="signal_axis"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                GraphHeight="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfExp:GraphViewer}}, Path=GraphHeight}"
                MinWidth="10"
                MinHeight="10"
                PenColor="{Binding ElementName=AxisColorPicker, Path=SelectedColor, Mode=OneWay}"
                PenWidth="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfExp:GraphViewer}}, Path=GraphPenWidth, Mode=OneWay}"
                MaxTimeValue="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfExp:GraphViewer}}, Path=_SignalDataViewModel.MaxTimeValue}"
                TimeUnit="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfExp:GraphViewer}}, Path = TimeUnit}"
                AxisDivisionUnit="{Binding RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type wpfExp:GraphViewer}}, Path = AxisDivisionUnit}"
                />
            <StackPanel>
              <ItemsPresenter/>
            </StackPanel>
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
              <StackPanel>
                <ItemsPresenter/>
              </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Yes, please check ItemTemplateSelector.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A simplest example I am taking here is to show Contacts with different background color based on their sex(Male/Female).

So this is how the ItemTemplateSelector class will look

```
class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {                
            Contact objContact = item as Contact ;

            switch (objContact.Sex)
            {
                case "Male": return App.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("TemplateMale") as DataTemplate;
                case "Female": return App.Current.MainWindow.FindResource("TemplateFemale") as DataTemplate;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and this is how you can use it in your XAML

```
<Window.Resources>       
    <local:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="myTemplateSelector"></local:MyDataTemplateSelector>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateMale">
        <TextBlock Background="Blue" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateFemale">
        <TextBlock Background="Pink" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Contacts}"              
          ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource myTemplateSelector}">  
</TreeView>
```